# Thin и OCI драйверы. Зачем использовать OCI?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, java

Программки на java c Oracle 11 (эти тесты с Enterprise по локальной сети).
Попробовал 2 разных драйвера (начинал с Thin, а сегодня наткнулся на OCI).

```
String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@clnode1:1521:db1";
String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:oci:@clnode1:1521:db1";
```

Тест, конечно, примитивный, в цикле 1000 раз исполняется небольшой запрос, `Connection` используется повторно. Без `OracleDataSource pool = new OracleDataSource();` (`Connection` **не закрываю**) работают примерно одинаково (1.75 с OCI и 1.7 Thin),
а с пулингом (`Connection` в программе закрываю, но оно, естественно, остается открытым в пуле) драйвер Thin (2.9 c), а OCI (3.95 c).

Если `Connection` закрывать в цикле (нет пула), то тоже примерно одинаково (57.2 с OCI и 58.2 Thin).

В [документации](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC) пишут, что Thin:

> is platform independent

а про OCI:

> The JDBC OCI drivers allow you to call the OCI directly from Java, thereby providing a high degree of compatibility with a specific version of Oracle. Because they use native methods, they are platform specific.

Кто может посоветовать, когда какой драйвер надо использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Сейчас имеет смысл всегда выбирать `Thin` версию драйвера, поскольку**

- Инсталляция native компонентов для работы `OCI` - сложный и совершенно бессмысленный процесс по сравнению с использованием одной `jar'ки`.
- [**Бенчмарки**](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/oraclejdbc_19/index.html?page=3) показывают, что реализация `Thin` драйвера не уступает, а иногда даже и превосходит `OCI`. Возможно, раньше ситуация была иной, однако с десятки это действительно так.
- Любой маршаллинг с использованием `JNI` *(что и происходит в `OCI`)* - это, очевидно, удар по отказоустойчивости и безопасности приложения *(поскольку мы выходим за пределы `sandbox'a JVM`)*

Comment: Вот я и задал этот вопрос, т.к. не увидел, чем OCI лучше по сравнению с thin, которым пользовался.

Comment: Драйвер становится все более актуальным из за перехода на java native

Answer (score 1):

Долго пользовался и тем и этим, разницы не заметил. Единственный минус OCI - необходимость наличия ораклиного клиента на пользовательской машине. 
Говорят, OCI поддерживается для совместимости.

Comment: Думаю, необходимость установки нелепого клиента на машину являются в таком случае решающим фактором. Thin драйвер просто работает, стоит подключить нужный jar.